# Script to run several instances of a program in parallel with arguments

Tags: automation

I want to be able to run one script (like a python script or whatever makes the most sense for these things) that will do something equivalent to something like:

```
$ program -i input -k 0.1 -m 0.01 &
$ program -i input -k 0.2 -m 0.22 &
$ program -i input -k 0.3 -m 3.03 &
```

I'd like to set up whatever parameters I want in a script and just type "python script.py" and have it run however many instances of a program that I want, all going in parallel in the background. I've seen people recommend `subprocess.Popen()`, but I don't know how to set it up to run multiple jobs in parallel. How do I accomplish this?

I've thought to make a list of commands and iterate through them, but 1) I think it would wait for the first job to finish before running the second job in the queue and 2) it seems inefficient.

Also, if writing this as a python script doesn't make sense, let me know what would be a better alternative; I've never done this before and don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Python solution using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module could look like this:

```
import os
import multiprocessing

def run_command(cmd):
    """ execute cmd via the shell. """
    print("starting `{}` ...".format(cmd))
    os.system(cmd)
    print("end `{}`".format(cmd))

def run_commands(commands, n_parallel):
    """ run commands (up to n_parallel in parallel). """
    worker = multiprocessing.Pool(n_parallel)
    worker.map(run_command, commands)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_commands([
        "program -i input -k 0.1 -m 0.01",
        "program -i input -k 0.2 -m 0.22",
        "program -i input -k 0.3 -m 3.03",
    ], n_parallel=2)
```

The centerpiece is the `map()` method of `multiprocessing.Pool`. This function takes a list of input values (in our case, the shell commands), and feeds them into another function, each in its own process, for up to the pool size of processes in parallel.

This simple script has one drawback, though: the output of the shell commands running in parallel will be all mixed up. This can be avoided by capturing and returning the commands' output in `run_command()` e.g. by using `subprocess.check_output()` instead of `os.system()`:

```
import subprocess

def run_command(cmd):
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        output = "ERROR in {}".format(cmd)
    return output
```

`multiprocessing.Pool.map()` will collect and return these outputs in a list, which we can the re-combine with the commands so that `run_commands()` returns a list of (command, output) pairs:

```
def run_commands(commands, n_parallel=2):
    worker = multiprocessing.Pool(n_parallel)
    for cmd, output in zip(commands, worker.map(run_command, commands)):
        print("{}: {}".format(cmd, output))
```

Now because we print the output *after* all the parallel processes are done, it's not going to get mixed up.

Comment: Thank you for this nice explanation. Storing the outputs in a list to be returned later is quite clever. Is it for functionalities like this that people tend to recommend subprocess over os.system?

Comment: os.system is the simplest way to "execute an external program", but also the most limited. All you get is the exit code. And sometimes that is enough. (You can use `>` and `2>` in the os.system command to redirect output to a file, or pipe `|` it into another program, but then you'll have to read that file in Python like any normal file.) The functions in subprocess allow you to connect to input and output of the external program in a more Pythonic way.